# ACF relationship field outputting unpublished content

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a relationship field that outputs posts from a custom post type. However, if I unpublish one of those posts, it still shows in the outputted code.

I'm aware it's possible to set the fields to only allow the user to select from published posts only (in the admin), but I'm not sure how to add a check in the ACF output code to see if the posts are published or not.

The most likely situation where this will occur is when the client has been using the site for a while and using the relationship fields, but then deletes or unpublishes one of the posts and forgets to manually remove them from the relationship field.

Is there a way to check this on the fly?

Code below:

```
<?php 
$holidays = get_sub_field('holidays');
if( $holidays ): ?>

<?php foreach( $holidays as $holiday): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($holiday); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $holiday->ID ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_title( $holiday->ID ); ?>
    </a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_post_status` to check the status of a post.

```
if( get_post_status( $holiday->ID ) == 'publish' ){
    echo 'This is a published post';
}
```

Also note that your use of `setup_postdata` is incorrect here. It is required to pass the global `$post` var to the function, otherwise any template function that relies on the global `$post` will output incorrect data. That said, you aren't using any of those functions, as you are using versions that allow passing of an explicit post ID, so you can just remove `setup_postdata` as well as `wp_reset_postdata`.

Comment: Thanks @milo. That works nicely within the foreach loop. However, this whole block of code also sits within a [flexible content](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) loop (which I'm performing a count on), so if possible I would like to get the number of published holidays before entering the holiday loop so I can perform conditional logic on the wrapping element, depending on how many published holidays there are. eg "if 2 holidays - output this html, elseif 3 holidays - output different html etc etc. I fear this is a separate question though.

Comment: Assign the value of your flexible content field to a variable like `$my_field = get_field( 'my_flexible_content_data' );`, then you can `var_dump( $my_field )` to see the contents and structure. It will be an array of arrays containing all of your fields, including post objects for the relationship field. You can then iterate through those arrays and count whatever you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use ACF's filters for this.  Put the following code in your functions.php.

```
// hide drafts
function relationship_options_filter($options, $field, $the_post) {
$options[‘post_status’] = array(‘publish’);
return $options;
}
add_filter(‘acf/fields/post_object/query/name=<YOUR FIELD NAME>’, ‘relationship_options_filter’, 10, 3);
```

more info directly from their site:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-post_object-query/